# Is this a common design pattern, possibly delegate pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I was curious what type of design pattern is this.

I a have method, say dao.read().

```
dao.read(a) {
    b = a.moreFields
    b.readField1();  // I want to move these calls ...
    b.readField2();
    b.readField3();

    a.rootField1();
}
```

Let's say I refactor that read method into this:

```
dao.read(a) {
    marshal(a.b)
    a.rootField1()

    marshal(b) {
      b.readField1();  // I want to move these calls ...
      b.readField2();
      b.readField3();      
    }
}
```

Is this refactoring into a design pattern?  Or just refactoring.  I am asking because I tend to that type of refactoring a lot and wanted to give it a name.  If I moved that method marshal to a delegate class, I guess it is delegation.

Comment: The name is "Extract method" and it is not a design pattern, but might be called a "refactoring pattern" since the pattern doesn't exist in the end result. The very action of extracting a method follows the pattern.

Comment: It does look like 'facade' as well, classic facade.  The marshal method in this case, a simplified interface to a larger body of code. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

Comment: No, facade is quite unrelated. It pertains to a case where you have a foreign API that is somewhat mismatched to your purpose, so you build a facade layer of code that adapts that API's interface to better fit your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a desgn pattern. At best it's "polymorphism", which is a basic feature of OOP. You could add the processing as a method for the classes A for object a and B for object b. hey would share the interface

```
interface Marshall {
  void marshall(<...>);
}
```

...but be different classes.

Once you did that, the obvious DP would be to use a composite that contains both A and B, and do

```
composite.marshall(<....>);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is not a design pattern but helper methods.